# How to ignore one field when using update query on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

Here is a User Model of my website.

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

        public $user_first_name;
        public $user_last_name;
        public $user_email;
        public $user_password;
        public $ur_id;       

        public function insert_entry()
        {
                $password = password_hash($this->input->post('user_password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $this->user_first_name = $this->input->post('user_first_name'); 
                $this->user_last_name  = $this->input->post('user_last_name'); 
                $this->user_email  = $this->input->post('user_email'); 
                $this->user_password = $password;
                $this->ur_id  = $this->input->post('ur_id'); 
                $this->db->insert('user', $this);
                return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }

        public function update_entry()
        {
                $this->user_first_name = $this->input->post('user_first_name'); 
                $this->user_last_name  = $this->input->post('user_last_name'); 
                $this->user_email  = $this->input->post('user_email'); 
                $this->ur_id  = $this->input->post('ur_id'); 
                $this->db->update('user', $this, array('user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id')));
                 return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }

}
```

As you see in the code I don't wont update the password when editing. So I have removed it from `update_entry()` function.

Nut when I calling `update_entry()` function it return following query.

```
UPDATE `user` SET `user_first_name` = 'Ruwan', `user_last_name` = 'Thilanka', `user_email` = 'ruwan1@example.com', `user_password` = NULL, `ur_id` = '2'
WHERE `user_id` = '7'
```

As you can see it auto adding the `'user_password' = NULL` to the query.

Why it is auto added even I have not it mentioned on `update_entry()`. How I remove it? (Please not that it should be in `insert_entry()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Why you are updating user ID in update_query() anyway.

Well, I suggest you to add WHERE in your SQL query, Provide user ID after WHERE. and then update the user table.

Below is an example function running in my system. You may find it helpful.

Make sure user_id field name I used is same in database, otherwise

change it with your user id field.

```
public function update_entry()
{        
    $postedData = $this->input->post();   
    $userID  = $postedData['user_id'];
    $refinePostedData = array(
      'your-field-name' => $postedData['user_first_name'],
      'your-field-name'  => $postedData['user_last_name'],
      'your-field-name'  => $postedData['user_email'],
    );

    if($refinePostedData!='')
    {
      $this->db->where("id", $userID);  
      $this->db->update("user", $refinePostedData); 
      return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here we use unset() fn to remove 'user_password' field from '$this' object and pass data to update.

```
    public function update_entry()
            {
                    $this->user_first_name = $this->input->post('user_first_name'); 
                    $this->user_last_name  = $this->input->post('user_last_name'); 
                    $this->user_email  = $this->input->post('user_email'); 
                    $this->ur_id  = $this->input->post('ur_id'); 
unset($this->user_password);
                    $this->db->update('user', $this, array('user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id')));
                     return $this->db->affected_rows();
            }
```